# how use addClass and removeClass jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i wanted .car-info dorpdown when .title-bar is mouseover so .car-info addClass .........

```
$(".items .title-bar").on("mouseover", function () {
   //i wanted .title-bar is addClass down
   // .carinfo on mouseover is addClass down
});
$(".items .title-bar").on("mouseout", function () {
   //i wanted .title-bar is removeClass down
  // carinfo on mouseover is removeClass down
 });
```

i wanted this style

[image]

when i am hover

[image]

see http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/n9rLF/3/

Comment: Those two methods should be as self explanatory as they come. Read the documentation and you'll figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".items").on("mouseover", function () {
    $(this).find('.title-bar').addClass('down')
    $(this).find('.car-info').addClass('down')

});
$(".items").on("mouseout", function () {
    $(this).find('.title-bar').removeClass('down')
    $(this).find('.car-info').removeClass('down')

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n9rLF/4/)

Comment: hey my frineds not mouseover .items class.. i wanted .title-bar class is hover

Comment: hey my friends u understand see my fiddle